# QSettings not returning any key in registry folder

Tags: c++, qt

```
QSettings settings("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run",QSettings::NativeFormat);
return settings.contains("myapp");
```

That won't return true even when I see the keys with regedit, if I try to print all keys, it returns an empty list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape \ characters:

```
QSettings settings(
  "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run",
   QSettings::NativeFormat);
```

Comment: Yes I do... I just realized I had escaped  the string when writing to registry, but not reading... :(